# How to change the back color of kryptontabcontrol in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, krypton-toolkit

I've downloaded "Extended Renderer Toolkit v4.4.0.1" From http://www.angelonline.net/Codesamples/Lib_4.4.0.1.zip.
But when I try to change The Tabcontrol background color, it appears in the designer but when I run the program it back to the default color. I've also tried to change it from the designer class and it appears on run, but also it come back to the default when i change any property in the designer for any control

Note : I'm using VS 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the KryptonManager, it handles styling for all Krypton components.